# Using joins & then using only a subquery?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Okay so I'm doing some SQL revision and I am supposed to do a query to "use a join and not using a subquery, list the publishers who publish psychology books." and came up with this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.pub_name, t.category
FROM publishers p
INNER JOIN titles t
ON p.pub_id=t.pub_id
WHERE t.category='psychology';
```

The next part is to do it using a subquery but I'm not sure how you would do that without using joins in the subquery itself? Also how would I print out every second author?

The [link](http://pastebin.com/hDTPShdc) is a pastebin to the database.

And this is the schema(I'm aware of the problem with the schema in regard to the discount table, not my schema).

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an IN clause:

```
SELECT 
    p.pub_name
FROM 
    publishers p
WHERE 
    p.pub_id IN (SELECT pub_id FROM titles t WHERE t.category = 'psychology)
```

Alternatively an EXISTS clause which is a little more complex but typically performs better:

```
SELECT 
    p.pub_name
FROM 
    publishers p
WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM titles t WHERE t.pub_id = p.pub_id AND t.category = 'psychology)
```

To get every second author:

```
SELECT 
    a.au_fname,
    a.au_lname
FROM 
    publishers p
JOIN
    titles t ON t.pub_id = p.pub_id
JOIN
    title_author ta ON ta.title_id = t.title_id
JOIN
    authors a ON a.au_id = ta.au_id
WHERE 
    t.category = 'psychology'
    AND a.au_ord = 2
```

Comment: Oh yes I remember doing the EXISTS last year, thanks.

Comment: Np :-)  Take a look at the last query for second answer and see if that gets you what you need.  I gotta run, but hope that helps!   Also, you'll notice I left out DISTINCT as I don't know that's actually required in this case.  Only use it if you absolutely must, as you end up taking a performance hit and for readability :-)  I gotta run, but good luck and have a great day!